# PDF file created on android device is invalid

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am creating a PDF file on android device and trying to write it. However the created file says "not an valid pdf" when I try to open. I get exception in code if I try to write/open.

error:

***Unhandled Exception:
10-25 18:51:32.853 E/mono-rt (21231): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.IOException: Sharing violation on path /sdcard/Download/test5.pdf".***

But the file is created in the path. I tried opening manually and got error that the file is not valid.

**I am using Xamarin.Android.**

Code:

```
        String filePath;
        FileStream fs;

        filePath = Path.Combine("sdcard/Download/", "test5.pdf");
        fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);


        var pdfBinary = Convert.FromBase64String(buf);

        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(fs)) {
            writer.Write(pdfBinary, 0, pdfBinary.Length);
            writer.Close();
        }
```

Comment: most probably your PDF structure is wrong.

Comment: I have not written anything to PDF. I am getting error in the line "var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);".

Comment: What is the value of `filename`? And why are you opening two streams?

Comment: `"sdcard/Download/"` That should be `"/sdcard/Download/"` i think.

Comment: `I am getting error in the line ... `.You mean the Unhandled Exception? Put that in your post please. You should have told that right away.

Comment: Apologies , I have Edited the error message. But manual access still says "Invalid PDF". Exception message received while executing is  "ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.IOException: Sharing violation on path /sdcard/Download/test5.pdf".

Comment: `But the file is created in the path`. How many bytes? And what is manually?

Comment: `Exception message received while executing` ??? What do you mean with while executing? It is very unclear if you talk about your code writing a file or are trying to share a file with an app the user choosed. You mix all up.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to C# file system sharing violation and not to anything concerning PDF structure: [Sharing Violation on Path Error C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541244/sharing-violation-on-path-error-c-sharp)