# How to create Root Tag only once

Tags: c#, xml

Trying to create XML file from xml File from FileStreame Writer class but it gives me an error lile `Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it.`

It creates the `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>` and Root Element Tag Twice my code

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(_logFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    string currentDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
                    xmlDoc.Load(fileStream);
                    XmlElement newelement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogData");
                    XmlElement xmlLogID = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogID");
                    XmlElement xmlLogDateTime = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogDateTime");
                    XmlElement xmlLogType = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogType");
                    XmlElement xmlLogFlag = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogFlag");
                    XmlElement xmlLogApplication = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogApplication");
                    XmlElement xmlLogModule = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogModule");
                    XmlElement xmlLogLocation = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogLocation");
                    XmlElement xmlLogText = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogText");
                    XmlElement xmlLogStackTrace = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogStackTrace");

                    xmlLogID.InnerText = _logIDPrefix + currentDateTime + randomNumber;
                    xmlLogDateTime.InnerText = currentDateTime;
                    xmlLogType.InnerText = ((LogTypes)Convert.ToInt32(logType)).ToString();
                    xmlLogFlag.InnerText = logFlag;
                    xmlLogApplication.InnerText = _logApplication;
                    xmlLogModule.InnerText = logModule;
                    xmlLogLocation.InnerText = logLocation;
                    xmlLogText.InnerText = logText;
                    xmlLogStackTrace.InnerText = logStackTrace;

                    newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogID);
                    newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogDateTime);
                    newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogType);
                    newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogFlag);
                    newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogApplication);
                    newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogModule);
                    newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogLocation);
                    newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogText);

                    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newelement);
                    xmlDoc.Save(fileStream);
```

thise code is executed more than one time but i just want to prevent to creating the `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>` and root element twise

Comment: Just a guess, try to flush the stream and set it's position to 0 before the call to xmlDoc.Save

Comment: You have asked the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337786/io-exception-was-unhandled/14337843), after your initial problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `Load` (which will leave the stream at the *end* of the existing file), and then calling `Save`. Don't do that on the same stream. You *could* just reposition it, but then you'll end up with problems if the new document is shorter. (It wouldn't be at the moment, but maybe in future.)

I would strongly suggest that you split this into three sections:

- Create a stream which just reads, and load the existing document
- Modify the document in memory
- Create a stream which just writes (truncating the existing file), and save the document

Comment: Doesn't this have the potential to hit performance?(load+parse+save an ever increasing file) You could cache log writes but then, you have a chance that you may loose the events if the app dies. Better use a file format that doesn't require a terminator, you could append write XML to a file, leaving the final close tag off, and add it when you need to parse it.

Comment: @Adrian: Sure, that makes sense - but it may not be an issue for the OP, and certainly wasn't the subject of the question.