# Writing to Filestream and copying to MemoryStream

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I want to overwrite or create an xml file on disk, and return the xml from the function. I figured I could do this by copying from FileStream to MemoryStream. But I end up appending a new xml document to the same file, instead of creating a new file each time.
What am I doing wrong? If I remove the copying, everything works fine.

```
 public static string CreateAndSave(IEnumerable<OrderPage> orderPages, string filePath)
    {
        if (orderPages == null || !orderPages.Any())
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        var xmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        var writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            Indent = true,
            Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"),
            CheckCharacters = false,
            ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document
        };

        using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            try
            {
                XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(fs, writerSettings);
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("PRINT_JOB");
                WriteXmlAttribute(xmlWriter, "TYPE", "Order Confirmations");

                foreach (var page in orderPages)
                {
                    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("PAGE");
                    WriteXmlAttribute(xmlWriter, "FORM_TYPE", page.OrderType);

                    var outBound = page.Orders.SingleOrDefault(x => x.FlightInfo.Direction == FlightDirection.Outbound);
                    var homeBound = page.Orders.SingleOrDefault(x => x.FlightInfo.Direction == FlightDirection.Homebound);

                    WriteXmlOrder(xmlWriter, outBound, page.ContailDetails, page.UserId, page.PrintType, FlightDirection.Outbound);
                    WriteXmlOrder(xmlWriter, homeBound, page.ContailDetails, page.UserId, page.PrintType, FlightDirection.Homebound);

                    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                }

                xmlWriter.WriteFullEndElement();

                MemoryStream destination = new MemoryStream();
                fs.CopyTo(destination);

                Log.Progress("Xml string length: {0}", destination.Length);

                xmlBuilder.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(destination.ToArray()));

                destination.Flush();
                destination.Close();
                xmlWriter.Flush();
                xmlWriter.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Warning(ex, "Unhandled exception occured during create of xml. {0}", ex.Message);
                throw;
            }

            fs.Flush();
            fs.Close();
        }

        return xmlBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Cheers
Jens

Comment: `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` should be `FileMode.Create`

Comment: Using Linq to XML would make this much much easier - also you're not showing how you actually decide on the file name

Comment: Changed it to FileMode.Create and this works, but now I don't get any xml back. The return string is empty.

Comment: The filename is a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FileMode.OpenOrCreate` is causing the file contents to be overwritten without shortening, leaving any 'trailing' data from previous runs.  If `FileMode.Create` is used the file will be truncated first.  However, to read back the contents you just wrote you will need to use `Seek` to reset the file pointer.

Also, flush the `XmlWriter` *before* copying from the underlying stream.

See also the question [Simultaneous Read Write a file in C Sharp (3817477)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817477/simultaneous-read-write-a-file-in-c-sharp).

The following test program seems to do what you want (less your own logging and Order details).

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ReadWriteTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(
                Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
                "Test.xml");

            string result = CreateAndSave(new string[] { "Hello", "World", "!" }, filePath);

            Console.WriteLine("============== FIRST PASS ==============");
            Console.WriteLine(result);

            result = CreateAndSave(new string[] { "Hello", "World", "AGAIN", "!" }, filePath);
            Console.WriteLine("============== SECOND PASS ==============");
            Console.WriteLine(result);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static string CreateAndSave(IEnumerable<string> orderPages, string filePath)
        {
            if (orderPages == null || !orderPages.Any())
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            var xmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            var writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
            {
                Indent = true,
                Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"),
                CheckCharacters = false,
                ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document
            };

            using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                try
                {
                    XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(fs, writerSettings);
                    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("PRINT_JOB");

                    foreach (var page in orderPages)
                    {
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("PAGE", page);
                    }

                    xmlWriter.WriteFullEndElement();

                    xmlWriter.Flush();  // Flush from xmlWriter to fs
                    xmlWriter.Close();

                    fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // Go back to read from the begining

                    MemoryStream destination = new MemoryStream();
                    fs.CopyTo(destination);

                    xmlBuilder.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(destination.ToArray()));

                    destination.Flush();
                    destination.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }

                fs.Flush();
                fs.Close();
            }

            return xmlBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

For the optimizers out there, the `StringBuilder` was unnecessary because the string is formed whole and the `MemoryStream` can be avoided by just wrapping fs in a `StreamReader`.  This would make the code as follows.

```
        public static string CreateAndSave(IEnumerable<string> orderPages, string filePath)
        {
            if (orderPages == null || !orderPages.Any())
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            string result;

            var writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
            {
                Indent = true,
                Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"),
                CheckCharacters = false,
                ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document
            };

            using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                try
                {
                    XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(fs, writerSettings);
                    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("PRINT_JOB");

                    foreach (var page in orderPages)
                    {
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("PAGE", page);
                    }

                    xmlWriter.WriteFullEndElement();

                    xmlWriter.Close();  // Flush from xmlWriter to fs

                    fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // Go back to read from the begining

                    var reader = new StreamReader(fs, writerSettings.Encoding);
                    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    // reader.Close();  // This would just flush/close fs early(which would be OK)
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late, but there seems to be a simpler solution. You want your function to generate xml, write it to a file and return the generated xml. Apparently allocating a `string` cannot be avoided (because you want it to be returned), same for writing to a file. But reading from a file (as in your and SensorSmith's solutions) can easily be avoided by simply "swapping" the operations - generate xml string and write it to a file. Like this:

```
var output = new StringBuilder();
var writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings { /* your settings ... */ };
using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(output, writerSettings))
{
    // Your xml generation code using the writer
    // ...
    // You don't need to flush the writer, it will be done automatically
}
// Here the output variable contains the xml, let's take it...
var xml = output.ToString();
// write it to a file...
File.WriteAllText(filePath, xml);
// and we are done :-)
return xml;
```

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:** It turns out that the `XmlWriter.Create(StringBuider, XmlWriterSettings)` overload ignores the `Encoding` from the settings and always uses **"utf-16"**, so **don't use** this method if you need other encoding.

Comment: Very nice and clean code. I'll give it a try and compare performance. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I ran a comparison check dumping 10000 orders to xml. Using SensorSmiths code it took 1198ms. Using File.WriteAllText took 1108ms. So not a huge deal. Also the xml somehow got encoded in UTF-16, even when specifying ISO-8859-1. Thanks anyway for the input.

Comment: Regarding performance, nothing surprising with all these caches nowadays :-) But the encoding issue is really annoying, thanks for reporting, I'll update the answer in case someone else reads it. Take care.