# ASP.NET MVC - error while trying to read and write to text file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

currently I am trying to create two controller methods reading from file and writing to same file:

```
public ActionResult UploadText(string name)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/text/"), name);

    var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
    ViewData["text"] = fileContents;
    ViewData["textName"] = name;

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TextPost(string textName)
{
    string text = Request["text-content"];
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/text/"), textName);

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, text);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Reading file content and writing to it works, but it cannot be read second time, `File can't be accessed because it is being used by another process` error appears.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not a deadlock and singletons are not solutions for deadlocks.

Comment: @ProgrammingDude How to do it properly?

Comment: What should happen if two concurrent requests arrive to edit the same file?

Comment: @ProgrammingDude **[File.ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx)** and **[File.WriteAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx)** do not require to close the file explicitly.

Comment: I see. Sorry about the confusion...comment deleted.

Comment: @Zdeslav Vojkovic there should not be such a case

Comment: If that's not the case, then I am not sure that the problem is with files being locked by your application. Any chance something else keeps them open? You can use tools like Handle.exe, ProcessExplorer, WhosLocking  or similar?

Comment: I once had a similar issue until I realized that it is me locking the file by checking it in the text editor and forgetting about it :)

Answer (score 0):

System.IO.File.ReadAllText and System.IO.File.WriteAllText both close the file after they and finished with the file per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx). The issue stems from the async nature of the web and well if you have more than one request while the file is open you will get the error you are seeing. Here are some [MSDN examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155757.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get you started.

Here are a couple more links for your pleasure

- [simultaneous read-write a file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817477/simultaneous-read-write-a-file-in-c-sharp)
- [How to both read and write a file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605685/how-to-both-read-and-write-a-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Unfortunately using 1st link's methods gives the same result