# Pass String from python script to C# UI

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio, logging, ironpython

I am executing a python script file from C#. That Python file is generating some logs, i have to get those logs back to my C# UI at run time i.e. every-time a log message is generated, my C# UI will be notified and the message is displayed in my UI.

Comment: why don't you use `FileSystemWatcher` from C# to monitor changes to log file?

Comment: Similar question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9757063/4815429 Look at using the [FileSystemWatcher Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

Comment: The problem i am facing here is
The Python logging (logging module) is not saving the file until the script is executed completely.
How can i use FileSystemWatcher to read from file which is not yet saved?