# is there a c# feature to listen to csv file update?

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I have a csv file and I would like to make some actions whenever a new row is inserted to this csv file.

is there such a listener in c#?

Thanks a lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# continuously read file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791103/c-sharp-continuously-read-file)

Answer (score 0):

There is a class FileSystemWatcher to inspect the file changes.
[FileSystemWatcher MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx). in your case, you just need to filter with "*.csv".

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not specifically a listener for a row being added, but there is such a thing, in .Net, as a `FileSystemWatcher`, which is a class that can monitor a file for changes.  With it, you can react to a specific set of changes to the file that you choose, but what happens is completely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FileSystemWatcher to watch an arbitrary file for change events:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher();
    fsw.Filter = "test1.csv";
    fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
    fsw.Path = "z:\\temp\\";
    fsw.Changed += Fsw_Changed;
    fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;    
}

private void Fsw_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.FullPath);
}
```

Comment: In this approach, i would be notified for updates on the file, but I would need to parse the whole file to find the last row, which is the new inserted row in the csv, am i right please?