# How to efficiently read new lines added to very large files

Tags: c#, .net, file, text-files

I am trying to implement an application with c# to retrieve only the new added lines in a very large text file (more than 1.5 GB). the new lines added by another service only adds records to this file, I highly need a method to read the last added lines efficiently.

Comment: How many lines are you looking at reading? The very last line or an arbitrary number of lines?

Comment: @Fabulous, if no way to know the new added lines and read them only, I may read the last 5 records and then compare them with the previous read.

Comment: You might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452902/how-to-read-a-text-file-reversely-with-iterator-in-c-sharp) for an efficient technique to read the file in reverse and then decide how many lines you want to read.
In it, a technique is offered to read the file backwards so you can leverage that to get the last lines in the file until you have the number you need.

Comment: You could read and store the file stream length before the modification.Then, after each append, position the stream in the last stored position and read to the end of the file. This of course is considering that your file only get appended.

Comment: @Magnetron, is this technique will load all the file bytes in the memory?

Comment: @Abdelrahman No, streams don't load all the file in memory, that's what make it ideal for large files.

Comment: This answer is the closest one of an implementation of this logic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42497394/5762332 just set `var lastReadLength = initialFileSize;` instead of `var lastReadLength = initialFileSize - 1024;`

Comment: @Magnetron Thanks, I really liked your solution