# Mirror file content in console

Tags: c#

I want to have file content displayed in console. I've managed something like this:

```
using (var file = new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
{
    while(true)
    {
        var line = sr.ReadLine();

        if (line != null)
            Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

I dont like this because instead of waiting for new content to appear, it is iterating over and over in `while` loop. Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: are you trying to monitor the file and show changes to as they come in or are you just trying to dump the file to the console?

Comment: @MikeJ I want to monitor the file and show changes.

Comment: sounds like you need to download tail and run "tail -f"

Answer (score 1):

Probably check if the file reading is not over yet saying `while(sr.ReadLine() != null){`

```
string line = string.Empty;
while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Per your comment looks like you wanted to monitor a specific file and keep writing it's content to `Console`. In that case, you should consider using [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1) in `System.IO` namespace. An simple example would be:

```
public static Watch() 
{
    var watch = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watch.Path = fileLocation;
    watch.Filter = "*.txt";  // Only text files
    watch.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite; 
    watch.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watch.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
   // Do some processing
}
```

You can see this existing post [c# continuously read file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791103/c-sharp-continuously-read-file)

Comment: I don't want to stop if file reading is over. I want to display real time file content (which is changing all time) in console.

Comment: @dafie then your question is not clear enough. Edit your question and mention the same.

Comment: I think stream reader is necessary to get only new content from file. Your example does not provide that.

Comment: @dafie I shown an abstract example to let you familiar with the approach and not a solid testable solution. You can research more on that as well look into the linked question for other approaches as well.